# how to create set button with angle and how to set Button image in relative layout

Tags: android, android-layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/contact_relMainHeader"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#16A180" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/contact_btnMenu"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:background="@drawable/scrol"
             />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/contact_btnLogout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:background="@drawable/lock" />
         <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="@drawable/centertext"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/contact_linearHeader"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/contact_relMainHeader" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#ee6958"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="Contacts"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#ee6958"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="Map"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/contact_relSearch"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/contact_linearHeader"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/contact_editSearch"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/contact_btnSearch" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/contact_btnSearch"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/contact_listview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/contact_relSearch" >
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This my Xml from which  am able to display Like layout like this [image: Link1]  i am not able to do how i will make the contact button angle shape [image: Link2] like given image how  i will set Sliding menu button  , Loci image and logout button . please help i have post layout xml file .

Comment: You need add your button inside framelayout and in framelayout add your button and the arrow image.

Comment: @GrIsHu 
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/contact_btnMenu"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:background="@drawable/scrol"
             />
in this what i will Pu t?

Comment: First make me sure you want to show the arrow like angle image which is below the contacts in your second screenshot image right ?

Comment: yes  and also sliding button and logout button and locii icon should be on between

Comment: From your first screenshot i think you have already set properly your sliding menu button,loci image and logout button.

Comment: yes but u see in main screen means second screen there padding an all

Comment: Try to set the padding of 5dp in your `android:id="@+id/contact_relMainHeader"` relative layout.

Comment: its working not ejeclty like that given image

Comment: Try to set image in `ImageView` not in `TextView`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all to leave some space in your top layout which contains Sliding menu button , Loci image and logout button you need to set the padding to your `android:id="@+id/contact_relMainHeader"` .

And second thing to show the angle arrow below your contacts button you need add imageview below your buttons inside separate layout.

Check out below code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/contact_relMainHeader"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#16A180"
        android:padding="5dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/contact_btnMenu"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:background="@drawable/scrol" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/contact_btnLogout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:background="@drawable/lock" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="@drawable/centertext"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/contact_linearHeader"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/contact_relMainHeader" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#ee6958"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="Contacts"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#ee6958"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="Map"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/nl_rllayutbelow"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/contact_linearHeader"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/nl_ivNotifArrow"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/down_arrow" /> //Set the arrow image of your angle.

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/nl_ivMesgArrow"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/down_arrow" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/contact_relSearch"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/nl_rllayutbelow"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/contact_editSearch"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/contact_btnSearch" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/contact_btnSearch"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/contact_listview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/contact_relSearch" >
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**EDITED:**

Try out below code for your Searchbox.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/contact_relSearch"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/nl_rllayutbelow"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/contact_editSearch"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/ic_search_category_default" 
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/delete" //Set drop arrow image.
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/contact_btnSearch" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/contact_btnSearch"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/delete"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

For partition between contact and map keep the `View` between them as below :

```
      <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/contact_linearHeader"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/contact_relMainHeader" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#ee6958"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="Contacts"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view1"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#ee6958"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="Map"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanx grish But There is issue one more coming

Comment: Serch Text Boz is desgin correclty i have Put that also like given sercreen

Comment: i have to Put image in that also there is partion so please check that also

Comment: Whats is wrong in that ? Which image you have put ?

Comment: u just set that XMl i will Put image from here search Box Part in i want set i am trying But my layout moving here and there e when i try to set that

Comment: contact_relSearch relalserch part plz check

Comment: Do you want to set image in `contact_btnSearch` Button ?

Comment: Remove the `ImageView` if you do not need it. And if you want to handle the click event of your dropdown arrow image then just set backgroung image of your `ImageView` and remove the left image from `EditText`.

Comment: thanyou very much dear friend

Comment: and one last thing there on Partition line you can see between contact and map plz tell me how i will draw that line or image

Comment: @user3587940 Just keep the `View` between them. Check out i have added code in my answer.

Comment: correct you are great.. can i have ur email id plz .. greate you are

Comment: please check i have Posted another Question ..related to layout http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23406097/how-to-set-cross-in-each-control-corner-and-set-margin-and-padding-in-android

Answer (score 0):

Genius try it for button angle..

1. **Drawable resources**

*button_pressed.png*

[image]

*button_normal.png*

[image]

2.**MainActivity.java**

```
   public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new   PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    /**
     * Declaration.
     */
    private Button contact, map;
    private TextView taskText;

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                false);
        /**
         * Initialize.
         */
        contact = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.contactBtn);
        map = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.mapBtn);
        taskText = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.taskText);

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        contact.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                contact.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pressed);
                taskText.setText("Contact list task");
                map.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.normal);
            }
        });
        map.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                map.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pressed);
                taskText.setText("Map View task");
                contact.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.normal);
            }
        });
    }
}

 }
```

3.**fragment_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.silambarasan.stackoverflow.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/mapBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:background="@drawable/normal"
        android:text="Map"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/contactBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/mapBtn"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
        android:background="@drawable/normal"
        android:text="Contacts"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/mapBtn"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/mapBtn"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="#FFFFFF" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/taskText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
</RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

4. **Result is**

   [image]        [image]

Answer (score 0):

```
// try this way, hope this will help you...
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lnrFirstHeader"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:background="#16A180" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgContactMenu"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/> // here set you header left menu image

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgHeaderLogo"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/> // here set you header center logo image
        </LinearLayout>
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgLogoutMenu"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/> // here set you header right logout image
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lnrSecondHeader"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/lnrContacts"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:background="#ee6958">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="Contacts"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:textSize="20dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"/>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/lnrMap"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:background="#ee6958">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="Map"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:textSize="20dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/> // here set your arrow image
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center">
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/> // here set your arrow image
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtSearch"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/> // here set your EditText right side image

   <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/lnrFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    // run time you have add respective fragment on second header item click like contact list and map.

   </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: can u please apply On Click Function so that if click on contact button then it should open contact list page and contact button should angle with down image if click on map button map page should open and map button should angle

Comment: for this you have just show/hide relative down arrow image on each layout click by default contact down image arrow shown with contact list.

Comment: But we have 2 page one for list and another is for map ... you getting what i want plz see my code dear plz

Comment: @user3587940, Okay dear i got it so for this you have to use one "Linear Layout" insted of "ListView",so have to add respective fragment on "Linear Layout" like one for contact list and another one for map i also edited my ans now plz check it.