# How to open two actvities on button click

Tags: android

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    String[] mob = new String[] { "Item 0", "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3",
            "Item 4", "Item 5", "Item 6", "Item 7" };
    ListView lv;
    Button contact;
    Button map;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.contact_listview);
        Custom_view cv = new Custom_view(this, mob);
        lv.setAdapter(cv);
        // contact.setOnClickListener(this);
        // map.setOnClickListener(this);
        contact = (Button) findViewById(R.id.contact);
        map = (Button) findViewById(R.id.map);

        map.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NextWindow.class);

                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });

    }

}
```

This My Class I have `2 Actvity` first `A` and `B`. In Both 
header is fixed Like Tab But i have to open on button Click 
two Actvity One for contact display and another map view as
 .

[image]

See this image, when I apply implement 
`onClickListener` then it shows Error, I don't know why this error is 
coming . 
Default page opened is `Activity A`: xml content for the activity can be found here:-
[how to create set button with angle and how to set Button image in relative layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23403437/how-to-create-set-button-with-angle-and-how-to-set-button-image-in-relative-layo/23404894?noredirect=1#23404894) here .

Comment: Share the logcat stacktrace.

Comment: it would be better if you use fragments instead of activities and Android ViewPager Class. Btw, make sure that NextWindow class is extending Activity Class

Comment: yes its Extnd from Activity class

Comment: I would suggest to go for the `Fragment`

Comment: @user3587940 Hey just keep your below layout fixed like `FrameLayout` and in that layout you can load the `Fragments` of your `Contacts` and `Map` Fragments dynamically on click of contacts and map buttons accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not launch two activities on a button click, result will be a single activity which will be invoked lastly.

You can use here fragments for loading the views that you want to display on both the activities.

You can use ViewPager for the same(good to use if views are swipeable).

A good documentation on swipeable views can be found here:
http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html

Here is another links you can refer: 
http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/