# how to set cross in each control corner and set margin and padding in android

Tags: android

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg03" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/gradient_bg_hover"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="139dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="Country"
                android:textColor="#a9a9a9"
                android:textSize="50px" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinner1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="49dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/gradient_bg_hover"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/editText1"
                android:layout_width="94dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:text="Code"
                android:textColor="#a9a9a9" >

                <requestFocus />
            </TextView>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="phone"
                android:text="Phone"
                android:textColor="#a9a9a9" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"
            android:text="Next"
            android:textColor="#0066FF"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Current results** and **desired results**

[image: Current results] [image: Desired results]

Comment: Which cross button you are talking about ?

Comment: cross textview and spinner i mean to say that see in screen 2 its i need to create plz help ...

Comment: and also see background color of text Box is white i need to create same as its plz help

Comment: and i ahve Next Button Image..

Comment: Which color you have set in your `gradient_bg_hover` selector ?

Comment: Well you have done so many things wrong as per your desire layout.

Comment: i just Point out gradient color i will change it from there u just fix and make from ur side gradient color

Comment: yes i know So i have asked from You

Comment: The text which you are interpreting as label is actually not labels but its hints. And your `country` layout whole is spinner.

Comment: yes u have any replacement for then please suggest me

Comment: @GrIsHu  suggest if u free then plz?

Comment: @GrIsHu if u free please check it .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try out below code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg03" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <!-- <LinearLayout -->
        <!-- android:id="@+id/layout1" -->
        <!-- android:layout_width="wrap_content" -->
        <!-- android:layout_height="wrap_content" -->
        <!-- android:orientation="horizontal" > -->


        <!-- <TextView -->
        <!-- android:id="@+id/textView1" -->
        <!-- android:layout_width="139dp" -->
        <!-- android:layout_height="match_parent" -->
        <!-- android:text="Country" -->
        <!-- android:textColor="#a9a9a9" -->
        <!-- android:textSize="50px" /> -->

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:entries="@array/colors"
            android:background="@drawable/round_bg" //Set the dropdown image as background
            android:spinnerMode="dropdown" />

        <!-- </LinearLayout> -->

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/selctor"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="1" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_weight=".80"
                android:background="@drawable/round_bg"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:text="Code"
                android:textColor="#a9a9a9" >
            </EditText>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".20"
                android:background="@drawable/round_bg"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="phone"
                android:text="Phone"
                android:textColor="#a9a9a9" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:text="Next"
            android:textColor="#0066FF"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**round_bg.xml**

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle" android:padding="40dp">
 <solid android:color="#EBEBEB"/>
    <corners
     android:bottomRightRadius="5dp"
     android:bottomLeftRadius="5dp"
  android:topLeftRadius="5dp"
  android:topRightRadius="5dp"/>
    <padding android:left="10dp"
        android:top="10dp"
        android:right="10dp"
        android:bottom="10dp"/>
</shape>
```

I hope this will help you.

Let me know still any issues.

Thanks.

Comment: But i have 2 Query how i will set set CountryName which is Written in Screen 2 in Text Field , then what i will set android:entries="@array/colors" ?which color

Comment: @GrlsHu tell android:background="@drawable/selctor" what about this

Comment: @GrlsHu Good morning u there?

Comment: @user3587940 `android:entries="@array/colors"` its a list of values which i have kept for binding in spinner. You can set your own values in spinner. And the selectors i have set for just for my understanding to create layout as needed. You can create or set your own designs according to you.

Comment: I need display Country Name i mean to you can see Country Name is there i want to display in textview plz help

Comment: It will set in spinner only whenever you will select any country name from spinner.

Comment: OK let me do then i will dear any ways Yoy Solution is really  great and every thing is done in SIngle time dearthanx

Comment: @user3587940 Ok try out let me know if any issues.

Comment: I tried But Spinner size increase when i text is in create i need to keep it Fix  Spinner

Comment: What are you trying to say ?

Comment: like if we select India Country then Spinner size deceased when i select United State then Spinner size increase i need to keep it Fix

Comment: Then give the fix width in dp whichever you want.

Comment: and CODE Text View and Phone-number EDIT TEXT is not layered

Comment: What do you mean by layered?

Comment: @ GrIsHu You Need XML

Comment: Whats missing now ? I just don't understand whats wrong now in your layout?!!! Its same as your desired layout.

Comment: See Code Text Box and Phone number text Box i Unable to set weight and aliigned with Phone textbox height and edittextbox

Comment: Try to adjust the weight of both it will be fixed.

Comment: what about height see that is not aligned with same Height

Comment: Update your question with your xml file.

Comment: dear i have down array Image But when i set background  Down array in right Side of Spinner how i will set @ GrIsHu